# How to use any command (such as git) with a normal user's ssh keys but sudo file permissions

Tags: files, permissions, sudo, git

I can clone a project as follows:

```
$ git clone git@mysite.com:root/myproject.git ~/bla
```

But now I wish to clone it to `/var/www`.  So I try

```
$ git clone git@mysite.com:root/myproject.git ~/var/www
```

But alas, I do not have permission to write to `/var/www`.  Sudo to the rescue!

```
$ sudo git clone git@mysite.com:root/myproject.git ~/var/www
Cloning into 'www'...
git@mysite.com's password:
```

What's this?  I am being asked for a password?  We shouldn't need no stinking passwords!

I am obviously sending the root user's ssh keys with the request, and as they have not been imported to the git repository, I am being denied.  In the past, my solution has been to temporarily change permissions of the folder or first clone it somewhere I have access and then move it using sudo, but would like to learn the right way to do so.

So... How do I use git with my normal user's ssh keys but sudo file permissions?

Comment: this will be problematical if your user home directory is encrypted or remote mounted such that the user-being-sudo'd-to cannot read the key materials

Comment: @thrig  Thanks, but fortunately it isn't.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a `ssh` agent running, do:

```
sudo SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" git clone...
```

That basically tells the `git` command started by `root` (or the `ssh` command started by that `git` command) to use your `ssh` agent (how to connect to it, which `root` should be able to as it has every right).

If you don't have a ssh agent running, you can start one beforehand with:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent)"
```

(and add keys to it as needed with `ssh-add`).

Alternatively, you can use

```
sudo -E git clone...
```

To pass **every** environment variable across `sudo`, not just `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK`.

I would **not** got with @NgOon-Ee's suggestion in comment to add `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` to the `env_keep` list. In general, you don't want to pollute `root`'s environment, as that's the user you start services as. For instance `sudo sshd` to start a `sshd` service would mean all `ssh` sessions started through that service would inherit your `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, polluting users environment with something they can't and shouldn't use. Even for other target users than `root`, passing that variable across would not make sense as the target user couldn't make use of that authentication agent.

Now, that only addresses key authentication. If you also wanted `root` to inherit your settings in your `~/.ssh/config`, you could not do that with `ssh` environment variables, but you could do that with `git` environment variables. For instance, defining a `sugit` function as:

```
sugit() {
  sudo "GIT_SSH_COMMAND=
    exec ssh -o IdentityAgent='$SSH_AUTH_SOCK' \
             -o User=$LOGNAME \
             -F ~$LOGNAME/.ssh/config" git "$@"
}
```

That is, tell `git` to use a `ssh` command that uses your ssh config file and agent and username instead of root's.

Or maybe even better, tell `git` to run `ssh` as the original user:

```
sugit() {
  sudo "GIT_SSH_COMMAND=
    exec sudo -Hu $LOGNAME SSH_AUTH_SOCK='$SSH_AUTH_SOCK' ssh" git "$@"
}
```

Comment: This won't help if there's anything in .ssh/config needed (e.g. a ProxyCommand). Also the right way for this solutions would be to use visudo and add SSH_AUTH_SOCK to env_keep

Comment: Thanks Stephane,  Appreciate your solution, but kind of surprised there is not a more intuitive one.

Comment: @NgOon-Ee, see edit.

Comment: Fair point in env_keep, but I would still prefer that in the (IMO most common) single user configuration. Sudo is used fairly rarely in modern Linux, and perhaps shouldn't even be used here (maybe I'll write up that answer as an alternative).

Comment: I ran into some problems with using git over https with git lfs (it wants to put in the password for every single file downloaded), so I tried swapping to an ssh connection but couldn't sudo clone in my production environment.

All I needed was that ``sudo -E``. Now it's working like a dream with my ssh key.

Answer (score 0):

File (or socket) permissions may be complicated if the key files (or socket) cannot be read by the user `sudo` runs as. This most definitely includes `root` if the files reside on a network share that `root` has no permission to, or should the home directory be encrypted which may again deny `root` access.

Another way on Unix systems that support extended ACLs is to use those, in which case you can grant additional write access on top of the usual base permissions:

```
$ sudo chown apache:www /var/www/html
$ sudo chmod g+s /var/www/html
$ sudo setfacl -m g:webedit:rwx /var/www/html
$ groups
jdoe webedit
$ ls -ld /var/www/html
drwxrwsr-x+ 4 apache www 25 Nov 21 19:42 /var/www/html
$
```

but the `webedit` group has permissions thanks to the `setfacl`

```
$ git clone ~/repo /var/www/html
Cloning into '/var/www/html'...
done.
$ ls -al /var/www/html
total 0
drwxrwsr-x+ 4 apache www   25 Nov 21 19:42 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root  31 Oct 19 20:39 ..
drwxrwsr-x  3 jdoe   www   14 Nov 21 19:42 a
drwxrwsr-x  8 jdoe   www  152 Nov 21 19:42 .git
$
```

there are however various gotchas around extended ACLs eg check how your backup software handles them, etc